# Library's Methodcount impact on app

Tags: android

I was reading [Glide Vs Picasso](https://medium.com/@multidots/glide-vs-picasso-930eed42b81d#.mwwcjnkaw)
Then I came across a sentence

> Picasso has method count of 849, while Glide has total 2678 method count. 2678 is quite a lot for 65535 methods limit of Android DEX file. You should enable ProGuard if you choose to use Glide.

Then I read

> Android libraries are great, but they come at a cost. Use this tool to avoid the dreaded 65K method limit of the DEX file format!

at methodscount.com

If we use a library with a large method count then will there be any effect on app performance? or is it just a number which have certain limit as 65k?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, it is just a limit. But many methods typically means lots of code and therefore larger file size. This will also have impact on installation time and memory consumption.

Comment: so the libraries with a huge memory count or lots of code will impact the apk size too?

Comment: Yes, unless you can remove unused code with tools like ProGuard.